# Process: Handle, Peak Handle, GDI Handles and USER Handles

Tags: process, handle

So I reading about [Handles and Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/handles-and-objects) of Windows and don't really understand what's the difference between

- Handles
- Peak Handles
- GDI Handles
- USER Handles

in **Process Explorer**.

I've already tested with a C# Windows Forms App creating lot of Labels to my form increasing USER Handles, but not Handles. 
So my question what is Handles?

Comment: Your question is tooooo broad. Handles are just a void pointer (mainly).

Comment: I don't think so, I ask it specially in Microsoft's Process Explorer.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer